# Backend & auth0 - store access token locally, in a variable or fetch a new one?

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

I'm calling an api from backend which uses auth0. I have been given credentials to fetch an access token, which once received, is valid for 24 hours. I'm wondering, what would be the best practice to handle these tokens. Should you

a) Save it locally in a database along with the expiry date, and then make calls with it until it expires

b) Save it in a variable (with the same intention), and fetch a new token every time the app is started

or c) just fetch a new access token each time you make an api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to keep the access token in memory - in a variable. As long as the variable is in RAM, it's a rather safe place.

If you save it to a persistent storage such as database, you should encrypt it. The same way as you would treat a password.

Fetching a new access token on each API call is just stressing the token endpoint and making your API calls slower. Getting a new token would make it easy to detect a token theft, but it would also make parallel API calls hard to handle or impossible.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on the same level with you regarding reasoning behind this.